# Python decorating property setter with list

Tags: python, list, properties, decorator, setter

```
globalList = []
class MyList:
    def __init__(self):
        self._myList = [1, 2, 3]

    @property
    def myList(self):
        return self._myList + globalList
    @myList.setter
    def myList(self, val):
        self._myList = val

mL1 = MyList()
print("myList: ", mL1.myList)
mL1.myList.append(4)
print("after appending a 4, myList: ", mL1.myList)
mL1.myList.extend([5,6,"eight","IX"])
print("after extend, myList: ", mL1.myList)
```

Result:

```
myList:  [1, 2, 3]
after appending a 4, myList:  [1, 2, 3]
after extend, myList:  [1, 2, 3]
```

The problem I am facing is that mL1.myList.append(4) and mL1.myList.extend([5,6,"eight","IX"]) do not modify the _myList attribute in the mL1 object. How could I do to resolve the problem?

Comment: Could you fix the indentation? I'm not sure where the second fiction is meant to be indented to.

Comment: It's not clear to me what behaviour you would expect. Should `append()` add to `_myList` (meaning the values won't be added to the end as one would expect) or to `globalList`? Either way, it's pretty clear this wouldn't work as the returned value is a new list produced by concatenating two other lists. Extending that won't somehow modify back.

Comment: append() should add to _myList, and so does extend()

Comment: Also, is it important that the list is accessed through the property? It would seem to make far more sense to make `MyList` act as a sequence itself by implementing `__getitem__()`, `append()`, etc... on it directly, and it would also make it easier to implement.

Comment: it's important for me to access globalList and _myList at the same time through a MyList object. That's great idea to implement append() by myself, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I define a method append() and a method extend() for the class object. It respectively appends to member myList and extends member myList.

```
global globalList  
globalList = []
class MyList():
    def __init__(self):
        self._myList = [1, 2, 3]

    @property
    def myList(self):
        return self._myList + globalList
    @myList.setter
    def myList(self, val):
        self._myList = val

    def append(self, val):
        self.myList = self.myList + [val]
        return self.myList  

    def extend(self, val):
        return self.myList.extend(val)


mL1 = MyList()
print("myList: ", mL1.myList)
mL1.append(4)
print("after appending a 4, myList: ", mL1.myList)
mL1.myList.extend([5,6,"eight","IX"])
print("after extend, myList: ", mL1.myList)
```

result is

```
>>> 
('myList: ', [1, 2, 3])
('after appending a 4, myList: ', [1, 2, 3, 4])
('after extend, myList: ', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'eight', 'IX'])
```

Comment: Thnak you for the suggestion!

Comment: The code is highly broken :) MyList does not derive from object, which breaks the setter property, so after assigning to myList it will be a plain list. Once this is fixed, append() will add globalList to _mylist for every call. The extend implementation is broken too, it should extend _myList, otherwise it would only extend the temporary list returned by the property. And last, the example is calling mL1.myList.extend instead of mL1.extend.

Answer (score 3):

I would subclass `list` and override a few methods:

```
import itertools

class ExtendedList(list):
    def __init__(self, other=None):
        self.other = other or []

    def __len__(self):
        return list.__len__(self) + len(self.other)

    def __iter__(self):
        return itertools.chain(list.__iter__(self), iter(self.other))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        l = list.__len__(self)

        if index > l:
            return self.other[index - l]
        else:
            return list.__getitem__(self, index)
```

It should work with just about everything:

```
In [9]: x = ExtendedList([1, 2, 3])

In [10]: x
Out[10]: [1, 2, 3]

In [11]: x.append(9)

In [12]: x
Out[12]: [9, 1, 2, 3]

In [13]: x.extend([19, 20])

In [14]: x
Out[14]: [9, 19, 20, 1, 2, 3]

In [15]: sum(x)
Out[15]: 54
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, it's interesting to see how you implement it. Hope you don't mind me asking some simple question: self.other = other or [], is short-circuit evaluation used here? so if the other parameter is not provided, then it's going to be empty list?

Comment: @user14042: Yep, if `other` is truthy (not `None` or an empty list in this case), it'll be returned. If not, the other side will be.