# Decorating list property

Tags: python, properties, decorator

Can I create a list property setter that would work with `append` and `extend` without overloading the class of list itself? `@property`/`@foo.setter` do not work in this case becaus append doesn't *assign* something to the list but modifies it in place. This seems like a common task but a google search finds no straightforward solution.

Comment: Please make an attempt, post the result, ask for help with the problems that arise.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380575/python-decorating-property-setter-with-list
It just advises to overload the class. Which I obviously can do, but it'll mean having a single-use class, which is ugly. And I might as well change API to call method instead of accessing list, but I hoped there is some more beautiful way of doing this.

Comment: Sounds like you are asking how to change the behaviour of a *built-in* container without subclassing and overloading one of its attributes.  You may get better results here if you post a question stating the problem you are trying to solve, give an example of a solution, explain why it isn't sufficient.  By starting with the problem you are trying to solve, some of the wizards here may have a different if unexpected solution.  In the meantime, maybe have a read on abstract base classes and metaclasses.

Comment: I just hope that there is some syntactic sugar I don't know that allows to do this kind of stuff. Of course, the actual problem (displaying exactly N last list items in `kivy` widget when list is an attribute of an object that isn't a widget) is easily solved by subclassing the list.