# Python property and setter for list as for int and strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties

I have a class with variables (`int`, `string` and `list`). And I would like to use @property to get value of variables, setter to set values to this variables. I could implement this conception for `int` and `string` variables, but not for `list`. Please, help me to implement it for list too.

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self._a = 1
        self._b = 'hello'
        self._c = [1, 2, 3]

    @property
    def a(self):
        print(self._a)

    @a.setter
    def a(self, a):
        self._a = a

    @property
    def b(self):
        print(self._b)

    @b.setter
    def b(self, b):
        self._b = b


my = MyClass()

my.a
# Output: 1
my.a = 2
my.a
# Output: 2

my.b
# Output: hello
my.b = 'world'
my.b
# Output: world


# Need to implement:
my.c
# Output: [1, 2, 3]
my.c = [4, 5, 6]
my.c
# Output: [4, 5, 6]
my.c[0] = 0
my.c
# Output: [0, 5, 6]
my.c[0]
# Output: 0
```

I have found similar questions, but they don't suit for me, because in this way calling operations for list would differ from int and string:

- [Python decorating property setter with list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380575/python-decorating-property-setter-with-list)
- [Python property on a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37564798/python-property-on-a-list)

Comment: Can you trim this down to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: @stephen-rauch Thank you. I accidentally copied the code twice from my notepad. I deleted a duplicate of my code.

Comment: Why do your properties *print* the value instead of returning it? And why do you even have properties? When people say that you don't need getters and setters in Python because Python has properties, that doesn't mean you're supposed to use properties everywhere; it means you're supposed to use regular attributes, and if it turns out you need to attach some logic to getting or setting the attribute, *then* you bring in a `property`.

Answer (score 0):

So I believe your misunderstanding stems from not realizing that *everything* in python is an object.  There is no difference between the `list`, the `string` or the `int`.  Note that in your implementation for the `int` and the `string` there is no difference, except for some names.

I have recast your example with a single property, and then assigned all of your use cases to it to verify that it works in all cases.

**Code:**

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_prop = None

    @property
    def my_prop(self):
        return self._my_prop

    @my_prop.setter
    def my_prop(self, my_prop):
        self._my_prop = my_prop
```

**Test Code:**

```
my = MyClass()

my.my_prop = 1
assert 1 == my.my_prop
my.my_prop = 2
assert 2 == my.my_prop

my.my_prop = 'hello'
assert 'hello' == my.my_prop
my.my_prop = 'world'
assert 'world' == my.my_prop

my.my_prop = [1, 2, 3]
assert [1, 2, 3] == my.my_prop
my.my_prop = [4, 5, 6]
assert [4, 5, 6] == my.my_prop
my.my_prop[0] = 0
assert [0, 5, 6] == my.my_prop
assert 0 == my.my_prop[0]
```