# Python property setter on a python list

Tags: python-3.x, oop, properties

I am trying to leverage on Python @property to modify a class attribute , which is of type `List`.  Most examples online assumes the attribute decorated by @property is a singular value, not a list that can be extended by setter.

To clarify question a bit : I don't just want to assign a value (a value of list of int) to property s, rather, I need to modify it (to append a new int to current list) .

My purpose is it is expected to have:

```
c = C()
c.s # [1,2,3] is the default value when instance c initiated.
c.s(5)

c.s # [1,2,3,5]
```

given implementation of `C` as below:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self._s = [1,2,3]
    @property
    def s(self):
        return self._s
    @s.setter
    def s(self, val):
        self._s.append(val)
```

Now if I do `c.s(5)`, I will get

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-99-767d6971e8f3> in <module>()
----> 1 c.s(5)

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

I have read the most relevant posts :
[Python property on a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37564798/python-property-on-a-list)
and
[Python decorating property setter with list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380575/python-decorating-property-setter-with-list)

but neither is appropriate to my case:
`__setitem__` can modify element of the list but i want to extend the list.

Use a global attribute is not acceptable for my current task.

In this regard, what is the best solution? (Or I should not expect @property on a mutable data structure from the beginning ? ) Thanks!

------edited-----

@Samuel Dion-Girardeau suggested to

> subclass list and define its **call** magic method

, but I am not sure I understand the solution.  Should I do something like this :

```
class C(list):
     # somewhere when implementing class C
     def __call__(self):
         # even not sure what i need to do here
```

Comment: Is there an explicit reason why you are avoiding `c.s = 5`?

Comment: You say that "Most examples online assumes the attribute decorated by @property is a singular value, not a list that can be extended by setter", but here you are never calling the setter, which would be done by assigning a value to `c.s`, e.g. `c.s = 1`. Here you are trying to call the value of `c.s`, hence the error.

Comment: Since `s` is a list. you can directly append to it, e.g. `c.s.append(1)`. If you absolutely need the call with parenthesis for some reason, you'll need to subclass `list` and define its `__call__` magic method to append to the list.

Comment: @SamuelDion-Girardeau Yes, I agree using `c.s.append(1)` is the best way to append a new element to current list.  I read the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37564798/python-property-on-a-list , where it states that "modify an element in the property you get the property and then set the corresponding element." so I think my `@s.setter` did that way : i.e. get the property that `_s` is a list, and then modify it by `self._s.append(val)` .   But I made a mistake here and got the error.  Any suggestion ?  Thanks ^^

Comment: @JacquelineP. In your code, you are never actually using the setter, I think this is what is causing the confusion. You can actually test that by raising an error from the function, you'll never see the error! Using the setter doesn't mean calling `c.s(5)`, it means assigning a value, e.g. `c.s = 5`. If the attribute was named more explicitly, I think this would make be more obvious. E.g. let's say we name the attribute "enabled". the getter is called e.g. if you `print(my_object.enabled)`, and the setter if you do `my_object.enabled = True`, *not* if you do `my_object.enabled(True)`

Comment: I realize those comments are all over the place, so I posted an answer, which hopefully is clearer!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Trying to summarize and exemplify my comments here. Hope this helps:

## Solution #1: Use a regular attribute, and `.append()` directly

The purpose of a setter is not to *extend* the value of the attribute, it is to *replace* it. In this regard, a list isn't any more different than an int or a string. In your case, since the value is a mutable list, you can simply call the `.append()` method directly on it.

```
class C():
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = [1, 2, 3]


>>> c = C()
>>> c.s
[1, 2, 3]
>>> c.s.append(1)
>>> c.s
[1, 2, 3, 1]
>>> c.s = [0, 0]
>>> c.s
[0, 0]
```

## Solution #2: Use properties, and `.append()` directly

The solution above works if there's nothing to check when getting/setting `s`. However if you need to use a property for some reason (e.g. you have some computation or checks to do, and want to prevent users from setting anything they want as `s`), you can do so with properties.

In this instance, I'm preventing negative numbers in the list as an example of a validation.

```
class C():
    def __init__(self):
        self._s = [1, 2, 3]
    @property
    def s(self):
        return self._s
    @s.setter
    def s(self, val):
        if any(x < 0 for x in val):
            raise ValueError('No negative numbers here!')
        self._s = val

>>> c = C()
>>> c.s
[1, 2, 3]
>>> c.s.append(1)
>>> c.s
[1, 2, 3, 1]
>>> c.s = [0, 0]
>>> c.s
[0, 0]
>>> c.s = [0, -1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 10, in s
ValueError: No negative numbers here!
```

Note where the error is thrown here: not if I call `c.s(...)`, which your question assumed to be calling the setter, but rather when I assign to `c.s`, with `c.s = ...`.

Also note that the users of this class will modify `_s` indirectly, through the setter.

## Solution #3: Subclass `list` to allow the attribute to be callable

Which I absolutely don't recommend at all because it breaks every expectation the users of this class would have, and I'm only providing it as a trivia, and because it allows the behaviour you asked for initially.

```
class CallableList(list):
    # This is the method that actually gets called when you `c.s(...)`!
    def __call__(self, *args):
        self.append(*args)

class C():
    def __init__(self):
        self._s = CallableList([1,2,3])
    @property
    def s(self):
        return self._s
    @s.setter
    def s(self, val):
        self._s = CallableList(val)

>>> c = C()
>>> c.s
[1, 2, 3]
>>> c.s(1)
>>> c.s
[1, 2, 3, 1]
>>> c.s = [0, 0]
>>> c.s
[0, 0]
>>> c.s(1337)
>>> c.s
[0, 0, 1337]
```

Please don't do this, and if you do make sure it's not traceable back to me :)

Comment: Thanks so much for detailed explanation!  It seems the solution 3 is the most appropriate for my task!

Comment: Under Solution #2, if you do `c.s.append(-1)`, the negative value will be appended to the list. The validation doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Adding to my `c.s.append(-1)` comment, I guess the result is expected due to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37564798/python-property-on-a-list.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
class C:
def __init__(self):
    self._s = [1, 2, 3]

@property
def s(self): return tuple(self._s)
@s.setter
def s(self, list_val):
    self._s = list_val

def add(self, *args):
    for arg in args:
        self._s.append(arg)

def print_c():
print('my list_props')
print('-'*5)
for p in c.s:
    print(p)
print('-' * 5)
print()


c = C()
print_c()
c.s = [8, 9, 10, 11]
print_c()
c.s = []
print_c()
c.add(100, 200, 300)
print_c()
c.add(400, 500, 600)
print_c()
c.s = []
c.add(*[i for i in range(100)])
print_c()
```